# ContextMenu shows less than 1 second

Tags: c#, wpf, contextmenu

I would like to control when the contextmenu of my control to show or not.

here is my code:

```
void MyControl_MouseRightButtonDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if ( some condition .....)
    {


            this.Focus();
            contextmeun.PlacementTarget = this;
            contextmeun.IsOpen = true;


    }
}
```

However, it just show up less than 1 second then disappear immediately. Why is that?

Thank you for all your help!

Comment: I don't think that's how you implement a context menu... you should be attaching the context menu to the control via its `ContextMenu` property.

Answer (score 1):

Probably because you're focussing the control that the context menu belongs to, then showing the context menu, however when the parent control gets focus, the context menu closes.

Try setting the context menu in Xaml instead to get the correct behaviour

```
<MyControl>
    <MyControl.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <!-- Define context menu here -->
        </ContextMenu>
    </MyControl.ContextMenu>
</MyControl>
```

Comment: Had the same thought, and you don't need to use Focus() at all anyway.

Comment: @user1184598 the answer by RV1987 demonstrates how you can show/hide the context menu based on a binding to IsEnable in a view model. Alternatively you can try the Popup control in WPF which is a templatable control within which you could place your buttons

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in pure XAML form, all you need to do is bind your `visibility` of context menu with a bool property containing your condition like this -

```
<YourControl>
  <YourControl.Resources>
     <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>
  </YourControl.Resources>
  <YourControl.ContextMenu>
   <ContextMenu Visibility="{Binding IsEnable,
                Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
      <MenuItem Header="MenuItem1"/>
      <MenuItem Header="MenuItem2"/>
      <MenuItem Header="MenuItem3"/>
    </ContextMenu>
  </YourControl.ContextMenu>
</YourControl>
```

Here `IsEnable` is a plain CLR property, in its getter you can have the logic for your condition depending on which you need to toggle the visibility of your context menu..

Comment: Thank you very much. However, the location will be fixed on the last click position. Could I control the position of the contextmenu shown as well?

Comment: Location will be fixed.?? I didn't get you. Context menu always open where you right click on your control..

Comment: No. For instance, I click on one location and its visibility = hidden.
Then I click in another location and set its visibility = visible, it will on the last location which is the hidden before

Comment: @user1034912 - Most likely binding failure. Did you even bother checking output window for any binding failures?